# Collection of certain length

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

Is there anyway if we can just pass a collection of certain length to a view?

I am trying to implement pagination thats why i don't want to pass entire collection.

```
 var <new View> = new App.Views.photos({ collection: <Collection of certain length> });
```

Is this possible? I don't mind adding another method that returns me a collection of certain length.

Update:

I created a another collection with same model and using it as a buffer everytime i paginate.
Let me know if this is a good idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470481/pagination-in-backbone-js seems to answer your question. See https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone.paginator too

Comment: @Pramod Well i could just use that but in my case i need to fetch more data before entring the next page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a paging method to your collection, that returns a subset (a "page") of the collection.

Something like this (not tested):

```
var PhotoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model:TestModel,
  getPage: function(pageNumber, pageLength) {

    pageLength = pageLength || 10;

    var first = (pageNumber - 1) * pageLength;
    var last = Math.min(pageNumber * pageLength, this.length);
    var page = [];

    if(first <= this.length) {
        for(var i=first;i<last;i++) {
            page.push(this.at(i));
        }
    }

    return new PhotoCollection(page);
  }
});
```

So you can retrieve any "page" from the collection:

```
//first page using default size of 10
photos.getPage(0);

//second page with page size 25
photos.getPage(1, 25);
```